# jQuery UI autocomplete: Getting reference to the ul

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I have 4 jQuery autocomplete textboxes. I need to add some style to one particular autocomplete list.

The ul is added to the body with the class `ui-autocomplete`. There is no link that would say which `ul` belongs to which textbox.

So i need to add the style to the UI after the Ajax Success or some  option that comes with

```
$("#srchList").autocomplete(
 source: function (request, response) {
          $.ajax({  .....
                        success: function (d) {
                         },
                    ......
                 });
          },
 open: ....
 select : .....
).data('autocomplete')._renderItem = function (liObj, item) {
    //Position the Autocomplete dropdown. This is not working !!!
    //$(liObj).parent().css({ 'margin-left': '-18px' });

    //Style the dropdown Item. (this works. the li is returned as string to jQuery UI and is added by the jQuery UI to the ul)
    return $("<li class='dropItem'></li>")
          .data("item.autocomplete", item)
          .append($("<a></a>").html(item.label))
          .appendTo(liObj);
};
```

There are some options like open :, positon: etc. But none of them get the ul-control for me to apply the css style over it.

Please help me to get the reference to the ul for one particular textbox.

DOM Structure: The textbox is somewhere inside the `<form>`

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"the ul is added to the body by Jquery UI. We cannot control the DOM structure as to where the ul is added. Updating an image of how my DOM is... – Raghav 5 mins ago" - you actually can influence where the placeholder ul is inserted by Jqueryui:

Use the "appendTo" option when initiating the autocompletes.
Have two empty divs, one where "standard" uls will be appended, one where you have your special style ul.

```
$(".the-standards").autocomplete({ appendTo: "#someStandardDiv" });
$(".your-special-autocomplete").autocomplete({ appendTo: "#someSpecialDiv" });
```

and then in your css, you can pre-specify fancyness like

```
#someSpecialDiv .ui-autocomplete { border: 1px solid red !important };
```

of access your special listing from jQuery by:

```
$('#someSpecialDiv .ui-autocomplete').css('border', '1px solid red');
```

Comment: always check the "options", "events" and "methods" tabs on jqueryui example pages - there's the juicy stuff. glad to have helped ,)

Answer (score 9):

You can add CSS class to that ul having class 'ui-autocomplete' by using :

```
$( elem ).autocomplete({
    source: ...
}).autocomplete("widget").addClass("whatever");
```

Class 'whatever' get applied to ul. see below img:
  [image: Class 'whatever' get applied to ul. see below img:]

Comment: Even better, just doing `$().autocomplete("widget")` gets the UL in question, and then CSS can be modified for just it.

Answer (score 1):

okay i hope i got you now, so you want to give style to each element in the autocomplete list
use `dataFilter` or `formatItem`

```
$("#srchList").autocomplete(
 source: function (request, response) {
     $.ajax({  .....
       dataFilter: function(data) { return "<span style='.....'>"+data+"</span>"; }, 
       // or  
       formatItem: function(data) { return "<span style='.....'>"+data+"</span>"; },
        //something like this, you can change it as per your requirement.
        success: function (d) {
                         },
                    ......
                 });
          },
 open: ....
 select : .....
);
```

Comment: no. i need to add a shadow to the entire box and remove the round corner from it. for each item, i found the way.. updating the code...
the items are added to the ul from jquery UI. so i cannot access the parent of the items..

Answer (score 0):

```
 select: function(event, ui) {
    // that's how get the menu reference:
    var widget = $(this).data('ui-autocomplete'),
    menu   = widget.menu,
    $ul    = menu.element,
    id     = $ul.attr('id'); // or $ul[0].id
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$("#srchList").autocomplete({
    source: ...
}).autocomplete( "widget" ).addClass( "your_custom_class" );
```

Comment: Please provide a little explanation of how this answers the question

Comment: This does not add a class to the UL created as the OP asked. This will append the class to the actual input the Autocomplete is being created on.